# PHP: How to get property of non-object (Error msg - Undefined property: stdClass::$0)

Tags: php

I migrated a Laravel project from one server to another server and everything works fine except the following specific piece of code (the following is just a sample code):

```
$test_obj = [
    (object) [
        'name' => 'name1',
        'value' => 'value1',
        ],
        (object) [
        'name' => 'name2',
        'value' => 'value2',
        ],
    ];

$first = (object) $test_obj->{0};
echo $first->name;
```

Error message on the standalone php command:

- Trying to get property of non-object on line number 14

Error message on Laravel:

- Undefined property: stdClass::$0

The weird thing is that the same usage works fine on the previous server (same php and laravel version). Can anybody give out the possible explanation and solutions to this?

Comment: `$test_obj` is an array with objects, not an object itself. Try: `$first = $test_obj[0];`.

Comment: or `$first = ((object)$test_obj)->{0};` will work on PHP7.2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see when you call

```
$first = (object) $test_obj->{0};
```

PHP will call $test_obj->{0} after changing it to object

so there is the error

```
Trying to get property of non-object on line number 14
```

And the `$first` object should be null and lead to

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$0
```

I tried to use this

```
$first = ((object) $test_obj)->{0};
```

But it worked on 7.2.x version of PHP only.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: Since `$test_obj` is a collection of objects and it's as easy as `$test_obj[0]` to access the first item, I don't see the point of casting it as an object first.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think he may want to use it as an object.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `echo` try to use `var_dump(); die;` to debug this kind of problem. it seems this is not an object it may be an array of object.